# How to generate a code for BNF?

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to define a custom set type:

```
notation bot ("⊥")

typedef 'a myset = "UNIV :: 'a fset option set" ..

definition myset :: "'a fset ⇒ 'a myset" where
  "myset b = Abs_myset (Some b)"

instantiation myset :: (type) bot
begin
definition "⊥ = Abs_myset None"
instance ..
end

free_constructors case_myset for
  myset
| "⊥ :: 'a myset"
  apply (simp_all add: bot_myset_def myset_def)
  apply (metis Rep_myset_inverse option.collapse)
  apply (metis Abs_myset_inverse iso_tuple_UNIV_I option.inject)
  apply (metis Abs_myset_inverse iso_tuple_UNIV_I option.distinct(1))
  done

copy_bnf 'a myset

value "map_myset (λx. x + 1) (myset {|1::int,2|})"
```

It seems that a code was not generated for `map_myset` function. So `value` can't simplify the expression in the last line.

I try to define the code equation for `map_myset`:

```
lemma map_myset_code [code]:
  "map_myset f xs = (case xs
    of myset fxs ⇒ myset (f |`| fxs)
     | ⊥ ⇒ ⊥)"
  apply (simp add: map_myset_def)
  apply (cases xs)
  apply (auto simp add: myset_def Abs_myset_inverse)
```

But I can't prove it's correctness because `map_myset` is defined using `MySetTest.myset.option.map_option`:

```
map_myset ≡ λf. Abs_myset ∘ MySetTest.myset.option.map_option f ∘ Rep_myset
```

How can I find a definition of this function? Is it possible to automatically generate a code for a BNF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're interested in code, I would suggest to use the lifting/transfer package instead of directly using Abs/Rep, etc. Then in many cases you get code for free.

```
notation bot ("⊥")

typedef 'a myset = "UNIV :: 'a fset option set" ..

setup_lifting type_definition_myset

lift_definition myset :: "'a fset ⇒ 'a myset" is Some .

instantiation myset :: (type) bot
begin
lift_definition bot_myset :: "'a myset" is None .
instance ..
end

lift_definition map_myset :: "('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ 'a myset ⇒ 'b myset" 
  is "map_option o fimage" .

lift_definition of_fset :: "'a fset ⇒ 'a myset" is Some .

value "map_myset (λx. x + 1) (of_fset {|1::int,2|})"
```

I hope this helps,
René